# File Server - Is it possible to allow users to view all files but don't allow them to access them

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-server, windows-server-2019, file-server

I am hosting a File Server on my local windows server 2019 computer.

The file structure is

```
Users
   -> User1
   -> User2
```

I have it so Domain Users can access and view the Users folder. I then have specific domain users to access the folders (e.g. User1 has Modify permission for his subfolder and files).

With this setup, each user can only see their own folder. Is it possible to allow the users to view all the folders in the directory Users, but can only access the ones they have permissions to?

**Server Browser**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr41I.png

**Users Directory Permissions**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaxeH.png

**User1 Directory Permissions**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbEqW.png

Answer (score 0):

This is because you enabled Access-Based Enumeration (the directory listing is based on the user's permission).

You can right-click on the share in Server Manager -> Properties -> Settings -> disable "Enable access-based enumeration"